# Apache Cassandra installation error Windows 10 : hotspot_compiler

Tags: java, cassandra, windows-10, cassandra-3.0

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.1\conf\hotspot_compiler
```

I am getting this following error in the command prompt when trying to install Apache Cassandra version 3.11.1.
I have already installed python version 2.7.
And the Java version is,

```
java version "1.8.0_151"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Please Help.
Note that I am installing the core apache cassandra server and not the datastax community edition.
Also for the record conf folder has a file named hotspot_compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by moving the cassandra folder from C:\Program Files\ to C:\cassandra.

I think the root of the problem is the space in the 'Program Files' folder.

Answer (score 0):

In C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf  edit cassandra-env and comment on line 357

```
 # Add sigar env - see Cassandra-7838                                                                             357  #$env:JVM_OPTS = "$env:JVM_OPTS - 
  Djava.library.path=""$env:CASSANDRA_HOME\lib\sigar-bin"""
```